# How to return collection object through restful web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have written some restful web services and methods whose return type was some collection object.  I could not return those objects, so I used a wrapper class that has that collection inside.

Is this the right way to implement or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I am using XML for the same.

Comment: Yes you could return those collection in a Wrapper object. And XML or JSON response would render the Wrapper with all the values in Collection inside the Wrapper.

Comment: @Jay Yes, I have done the same. I was looking if theres any better way to do it?

Comment: That's the way I have implemented my APIs. To my knowledge I think this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a collection without a wrapper object can indeed make life awkward depending on your intermediate format. The wrapper also has the advantage that in future you can add more information to the returned object to go alongside the list, so it's not as wasteful as it may seem.

Comment: Yes. But it adds number of classes in your application.

Comment: Classes are a good thing (within reason) don't be scared to create them. Put them in their own package so it's nicely organized and it's fine.